# Using component encapsulated in a module from other module in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components, angular-module, ng-modules

I am developing an angular 4 app and I have two modules, the first module encapsulate some features that I need to use in others modules. For example I have the first module called SRModule I have imported SrCrComponent component:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'; 

// module imports
import { SrCrComponent} from './sr-cr';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    SrCrComponent
  ],
  declarations: [
    SrCrComponent
  ]
})
export class SRModule {}
```

I want to use SrCrComponent in other component of another module, but I can get figure out how to use.

In my second module called ReportsModule, I have imported SRModule on it

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CPComponent } from './cp/cp.component';
import { SRModule } from "../sr-module/sr.module";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SRModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    CPComponent
  ]
})
export class ReportsModule { }
```

My question here is, how to use SrCrComponent component declared inside CPComponent on ReportsModule?

This is my CPComponent ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-chart-period',
  templateUrl: './chart-period.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chart-period.component.css']
})
export class CPComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

In my html of CPComponent I have a sr-gg component but not work,

```
<h2> Bar Chart</h2>
<sr-gg></sr-gg>
```

Oviously `'sr-g' is not a known element` in ReportsModule, in fac, this is the error that console is showed me, but I don't know where I need to declare or it should be inherit when I import SrCrComponen.

Comment: Have tou added selector `sr-cr` in you component else everything seems fine it should work

Comment: Please add spurce of your `SrCrComponent` here

Comment: I have fixed some bad names in my code example, I delete some declarations and reduce the length of component name to simplify the example

Comment: in which component you've added the selector `sr-gg` ?

Comment: @BabarBilal in CPComponent

Comment: in `CPComponent` you've called `<sr-gg></sr-gg>` but in where is `sr-gg` component ?

Answer (score 2):

ReportsModule imports SRModule and thereby everything from SRModule that is pointed out in exports : []  which in your case is SrCrComponent. I assume CpComponent should be part of ReportsModule, i.e CpComponent should be mentioned in declarations : [] for ReportsModule. You mention sr-gg as a component so if that should be declared in SrModule then that exports should look like exports : [SrCrComponent, SrGGComponent]

```
 @NgModule({
      imports: [
         CommonModule
      ],
      exports: [
         SrCrComponent, SrGGComponent
      ],
      declarations: [
        SrCrComponent, SrGGComponent
      ]
})
export class SRModule {}
```

and

```
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        SRModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        ReportsComponent,
        ChartPeriodComponent,
        ChartSegmentationComponent,
        CpComponent
      ]

})

export class ReportsModule { }
```

Then it should work